# Criterion Restrictions.like and numbers and dates

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I'm using Hibernate over mySQL. In mySQL you can put LIKE in queries even on number (like double) parameters and dates, for example you can write:

```
select * from sillytable where field like "3.33%"
```

and this will work. The problem is that I can't do this in criterion using Restrictions.like, in fact it throws an exception says that it can't cast a String to a Date or Double.

How can I do this with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the only *good* solution that did what I meant to do was using HQL.
There is no clear way to do this in Criteria

Answer (score 0):

I think this is actually:

```
x => 3.33 and x < 3.34
```

In hibernate this is:

```
Restriction.between("field", 3.33, 3.34)
```

Between is defined as `(min <= expr AND expr <= max)`. So the upper bound has to be changed to the biggest value starting with 3.33. (Caveat: You could have a representation failure if the upper bound is not representable and 3.34 is representated with 3.33999... . You would miss this one value if you do nextAfter with this already valid bound.)

```
Restriction.between("field", 3.33, Math.nextAfter(3.34, -Double.MAX_VALUE));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria crit;

try {
  crit = session.createCriteria(sillytable.class, "st");
  crit.add(Restrictions.like("field", number + "%"));
}
```

Comment: this is not the case, it wont work if "field" is date for instance (don't know for number, date would be more useful).

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to stick to `Hibernate` criteria use `Restrictions.sqlRestriction` instead of `Restrictions.like` as explained below:

```
Restrictions.sqlRestriction(" CAST({alias}.field AS CHAR) LIKE ('%" + number + "%')")
```